# GTKMM on RHEL3?

Tags: linux, gtk, gtkmm

How can I install GTKMM on a Red Hat enterprise Linux 3?

Comment: You'd probably be more successful asking on Super User (http://superuser.com).

Comment: Okay, let me try posting there too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dag Wieers has [packages available](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/gtkmm2/) for EL3. Don't expect anything recent though.